Azure AD B2C Auth Issues
I am trying to setup my app so it can use Microsoft as an authorization option using Azure AD B2C
I got it all configured how I thought I needed to and it works for anyone with a personal account from outlook, hotmail, live and so on. It also worked for one person with a Microsoft account from this company we are trying to work with, he is a higher up and I am assuming has a higher tier license.
All of the people who work under him though it says there email isnt a microsoft email.

My expectation was that I set this up to accept any email whether its from a business or personal and it would just work, but of course it doesnt.
Any help would be appreciated

Personal Microsoft accounts and enterprise ones are different. Corporate accounts don't fit B2C use case. You can't just allow any corporate Microsoft account, it doesn't work like that.

B2C is for customer accounts, e.g. joe@someemailprovider.com.
Entra ID is for corporate accounts, i.e. domain joined, e.g. joe@domain.onmicrosoft.com.
Don't confuse this with MSA accounts (used to be called Windows Live).
Anyone can have one of these, and B2C accepts them.
If you want to use corporate accounts, you have to federate with Entra ID.

I see that makes more sense. Appreciate your response, I will see if I can get it working the way I need it to

So I guess the real problem is I cant figure out how to setup up the self service signup. They need to be able to use microsoft to verify, but they arent part of my tenant and I dont want to configure it for every company we work with.

When you say "Microsoft", do you mean domain joined or MSA?

There is no self-service setup for non-local accounts. For both domain-joined and MSA accounts, these accounts are managed outside of B2C. When they federate, B2C creates a "shadow account" for them automatically.

You only need to set up one federation for MSA, and one federation for multi-tenant domain joined - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider
